# SSIS error handling for multiple CSV tables into one SQL table

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I was asked to load 15 different CSV into 15 SQL tables. I am using truncate and load into tables with 15 different packages in one solution. But here the requirement is the client wants to load  all the error details in one single error SQL table. They want a generic table where it stores from which package the error came, which row, where it is failing, which day it failed etc.

Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the event handlers in each package and store the errors in an audit database.

[image]

There are two sections in every SSIS Event Handlers:

Executable: You can use this it to select the Task, Containers on which you want to apply Event handling in SSIS.

Event Handler:  has all the event. You can select the event that you want to handle.

You will choose the Event Handler `OnError`:

[image]

Then create a table in SQL Server under schema Audit for example :

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA Audit;

CREATE TABLE Audit.PackageError
(
 Pk_ID NVARCHAR(100),
 Machine_Name Nvarchar(200),
 Package_Name Nvarchar(200),
 Task_Name Nvarchar(200),
 Error_Code INT,
 Error_Description Nvarchar(Max),
 Dated Datetime
)
```

After selecting the OnError for the Package, add an Execute SQL Task to the Event Handlers :

[image]

In the Execute SQL Task, configure the database connection to the your audit database and setup the Expression as shown below :

[image]

Comment: Thanks Amira for the response. I did exactly the same but when an error happens, the whole package is failing and the error handling is also failing. 
I am looking for a process in such a way that the package wont tell fail but log the error in the error table and continue running the process and load the correct data.

Comment: @Prashanthi please share with us your errors so we can help you.

Comment: Here is the error.

[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "INSERT INTO [tmm].[PackageError]

     VALUES({606..." failed with the following error: "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

The package is failing along with the event handler... (sorry but unable to share a screenshot.. I am new to this platform and couldnt find attachment option or paste option)

Comment: It looks like I have made this question complicated.. I would like to reiterate my questions..
1) can we send error rows to a SQL table instead of a flat file?
2) If not to a SQL Table, can we do the same in one flat file for all packages/tables
3) can we do that error table a common error table for multiple packages( each package does the same thing which is load data from csv file to a SQL table)
4) The above error table doesn't show which row is having error? can we do that somehow?
5) If all the above can be done, please share some insight on how exactly to do?

Much appreciated!